# Rails: Each loop that only shows unique associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an situation where I want to show an each loop of 'updates'. Each update had a game associated with it (game_id). Some times there are updates that have the same game as other updates. How do I modify the loop so that it only shows unique updates? (in the example code below, I don't want to show the same game thumbnail twice)

**In the view:**

```
  <% current_user.updates.each do |update| %>

     <img src="<%= update.game.thumbnail %>" />

  <% end %>
```

**In the updates model**

belongs_to :user

belongs_to :game

**In the game model**

has_many :users

has_many :updates

**In the user model**

has_many :updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a half a dozen ways to do this.  I would probably use a scope on the update model something like:

```
scope :most_recent, group(:game_id).order('created_at ASC')
```

This will give you the most recent entry by date for each game id.

Then in your view

```
<% current_user.updates.most_recent.each do |update| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to modify like 
      current_user.updates.uniq